# How to setup Fabric/Crashlytics without installing their client app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I just setup a fabric.io account. Part of the new user flow is for me to download and run the Mac app.

[image]

Is there a way to continue the setup process and get my API key without running their app? I can get the [Crashlytics directly](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) via CocoaPods.

I tried navigating to https://fabric.io/settings/organizations but it always redirects me to https://fabric.io/onboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

You can get any of the parts of Fabric and your API key from https://fabric.io/kits/ after selecting the part of Fabric you want to install.

When you are at the page with the link you provided (https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) The API key is given in [image: Step 3]. If you're not logged in to the site or still need to verify your Fabric account's email address, then you'll be prompted for either one of those actions before you can get the key.

Comment: The key is indeed there, thanks for the quick answer